# How can I use a system icon in my application?

Tags: programming, vala

I would like to use the refresh icon in my application. Rather than creating my own icon I would like to use the refresh icon used in Files, in a way that the icon will be updated when the user uses a different theme.

I found the refresh icon in this path "/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/16x16/actions/view-refresh.png".

However, instead of using the hardcoded path in the code I would like to use a reference path or alias to the above icon which will show the default refresh icon based on the theme in use. In case the image cannot be located I can default to a hard coded image which will be kept in my application default icon location.

Appreciate any sample vala code or pointers to implement the above.

Thanks,
Sid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just load the icon using the name. Gtk will select the one appropriate for the current theme. In your case, you would use something like:

```
var icon = Gtk.Image.from_icon_name("view-refresh", Gtk.IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR);
```

See [valadoc](http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Image.Image.from_icon_name) for more information.

Comment: Many thanks for the swift response and spot on with your suggestion as well. I went with the Button Image as I thought it gives the clickable action better than just a image itself. This is what I used:    Button ports_refresh_button = new Button.from_icon_name ("view-refresh", IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR);    .Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: As an afterthought I kind of like the refresh icon in the header bar in Pantheon Files (right end) better than the stock view-refresh one. What would be the name to get the Pantheon Files reload icon. <br> Another icon comes if I mention "reload" instead of "view-refresh" - is that better supported ?

Comment: I believe the one used in Files is `view-refresh-symbolic`.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion about "view-refresh-symbolic" - spot on again ! Is there any method or documentation on these icons or is it just your knowledge and exploration ? Many thanks again!

Comment: Most of my knowledge is through exploration of `/usr/share/icons`. I did find the [icon theme specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html), which is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I have bookmarked the icon specs for further reference.